# How to know when my Android app is terminating?

Tags: android, terminate, alarm

I need to cancel a repeating alarm when my app terminates. The problem is I have several activities and since they can be killed at any time, how can I determine when the last activity is being shutdown so I can call my alarm canceling method?

Answer (score -1):

There's no 100% reliable way. The best thing you can do is subclass `Application` and override `onTerminate()`.

Comment: Of course, there's no guarantee onTerminate() will ever get called either. And alarms only get removed if the OS reboots. So Im thinking now that I best not use setRepeating() in AlarmManager. Maybe Im better off scheduling the next alarm inside my alarm handler and have it check to see if app is running?

Comment: @Eno I think yes. `AlarmManager` is likely starting a `Service`, right? Make sure it doesn't bring the `Application` up.